# SQL Group by column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL dbo.bugetyear & Output below.

```
 NameofAccount    BudgetMonth    Balance      AccountCategory      Year
  sales              1            -344.78        income              2018
  sales              2            -2744.78       income              2018
  sales              3            -8745.78       income              2018
  INTEREST INC       1             7866          Interest income     2018
  INTEREST INC       2             1766          Interest income     2018
```

I want to sum by Account Category.

```
  NameofAccount      Balance      AccountCategory      Year       
     sales           -3089.56       income              2018
   INTEREST INC       9632           Interest income    2018
```

Comment: If you want to do a sum, then use `GROUP BY`.  Your data values don't look like a `SUM()`, though.

Comment: Select NameofAccount , BudgetMonth, Sum(Balance),AcctCategory,year from dbo.budgetyear                            group by  NameofAccount Balance,AcctCategory,year

Comment: but still those account names are repeating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there an error in the sales sum? If so, here is a solution:

```
SELECT
        NameOfAccount,
        SUM(Balance) AS Balance,
        AccountCategory,
        Year
FROM dbo.bugetyear
GROUP BY NameOfAccount, AccountCategory, Year
```